# tooltip function for onmouseover and onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have 5 links with tooltip hovers on each one except the last one. The reason the last one is different is because I'm using the tooltip to show the user their data was copied after the link was clicked. I would still like to have a hover for that link like the other ones that tells the user what the button does before they click it. I've included a sample below. I'd appreciate it if someone could help me figure out how to add the hover tool tip on the last link as well as having it still say "copied" after it was clicked.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({trigger: 'click',placement: 'bottom'});
 });
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('[card-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
 });
 function hideTooltip() {
   setTimeout(function() {
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');
   }, 1000);
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="padding:50px;">
<a href="#" card-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit link data" class="card-link">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pencil-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456l-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z" />
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z" />
  </svg>
</a>
<a href="#" card-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="View link stats" class="card-link">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bar-chart-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M1 11a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1v-3zm5-4a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v7a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H7a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V7zm5-5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2z" />
  </svg>
</a>
<a href="#" card-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visit link" class="card-link">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-up-right-square-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M14 0a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12zM5.904 10.803L10 6.707v2.768a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V5.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H6.525a.5.5 0 1 0 0 1h2.768l-4.096 4.096a.5.5 0 0 0 .707.707z" />
  </svg>
</a>
<a href="#" card-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="View link" class="card-link">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-right-square-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M0 14a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12zm4.5-6.5h5.793L8.146 5.354a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708l3 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8.5H4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1z" />
  </svg>
</a>
  <a href="#" id="#hi" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Copied!" data-placement="bottom" data-clipboard-text="{{base_url}}{{url.short_url}}" onclick="hideTooltip()" onmouseover="$('#hi').tooltip({title:'Copy'})" class="card-link">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-files" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path d="M13 0H6a2 2 0 0 0-2 2 2 2 0 0 0-2 2v10a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h7a2 2 0 0 0 2-2 2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2zm0 13V4a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h7a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v10a1 1 0 0 1-1 1zM3 4a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h7a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v10a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H4a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V4z" />
    </svg>
  </a>
  
  </div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('[card-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({title: function () { return this.dataset.title }});
 });

 function update(title) {
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').attr('data-title', title);
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('show');
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="padding:50px;">
<a href="#" card-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit link data" class="card-link">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pencil-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456l-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z" />
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z" />
  </svg>
</a>
<a href="#" card-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="View link stats" class="card-link">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bar-chart-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M1 11a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1v-3zm5-4a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v7a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H7a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V7zm5-5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2z" />
  </svg>
</a>
<a href="#" card-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visit link" class="card-link">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-up-right-square-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M14 0a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12zM5.904 10.803L10 6.707v2.768a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V5.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H6.525a.5.5 0 1 0 0 1h2.768l-4.096 4.096a.5.5 0 0 0 .707.707z" />
  </svg>
</a>
<a href="#" card-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="View link" class="card-link">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-right-square-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M0 14a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12zm4.5-6.5h5.793L8.146 5.354a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708l3 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8.5H4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1z" />
  </svg>
</a>
  <a href="#" id="#hi" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Copy" data-placement="bottom" data-clipboard-text="{{base_url}}{{url.short_url}}" onclick="update('Coppied!')" onpointerenter="update('Copy')" class="card-link">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-files" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path d="M13 0H6a2 2 0 0 0-2 2 2 2 0 0 0-2 2v10a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h7a2 2 0 0 0 2-2 2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2zm0 13V4a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h7a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v10a1 1 0 0 1-1 1zM3 4a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h7a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v10a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H4a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V4z" />
    </svg>
  </a>
  
  </div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```